# Searching for and manipulating the content of a keyword in a huge file

Tags: python

I have a huge HTML file that I have converted to text file. (The file is Facebook home page's source). Assume the text file has a specific keyword in some places of it. For example: "some_keyword: [bla bla]". How would I print all the different bla blas that are followed by some_keyword?

```
{id:"1126830890",name:"Hillary Clinton",firstName:"Hillary"}
```

Imagine there are 50 different names with this format in the page. How would I print all the names followed by "name:", considering the text is very large and crashes when you read() it or try to search through its lines.

Sample File:

`shortProfiles:{"100000094503825":{id:"100000094503825",name:"Bla blah",firstName:"Blah",vanity:"blah",thumbSrc:"https://scontent-lax3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c19.0.64.64/p64x64/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?oh=3b26bb13129d4f9a482d9c4115b9eeb2&oe=5883062B",uri:"https://www.facebook.com/blah",gender:2,i18nGender:16777216,type:"friend",is_friend:true,mThumbSrcSmall:null,mThumbSrcLarge:null,dir:null,searchTokens:["Bla"],alternateName:"",is_nonfriend_messenger_contact:false},"1347968857":`

Comment: Is this data stored in JSON format

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri No. It was originally HTML that I converted to a txt file. Would keeping it as HTML help?

Comment: Added the answer. since you are person responsible for witting the data to file. Write it in valid json format. Check JSON module in python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: You need to define this format more clearly. It is not properly formatted JSON. Perhaps CSS data attribute?

Comment: @dawg The file is your Facebook home page's source. It's an HTML file.

Comment: @dawg I added a sample of the file in my question.

Comment: How did you "convert it to a text file"? HTML **is** text.

Comment: @MattDMo I mean the format, which might be completely irrelevant as you say.

Comment: @all  data in the example is an cut from html page of facebook, part with JavaScript dictionary

Comment: @Nathan you have two ways - parse html by regexp or any html processing framework to get javascript dict you needed and then parse that dict using json module (formats r not quite the same, but it could be handled by replace).  Second way is to use Facebook Graph API and python lib for queering data from Facebook API - Facebook-SDK

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, since you are the person responsible for writting the data to the file. Write the data in JSON format and read it from file using [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) as:

```
import json
json_file = open('/path/to/your_file')
json_str = json_file.read()
json_data = json.loads(json_str)


for item in json_data:
    print item['name']
```

**Explanation:**

Lets say `data` is the variable storing

```
{id:"1126830890",name:"Hillary Clinton",firstName:"Hillary"}
```

which will be dynamically changing within your code where you are performing write operation in the file. Instead append it to the list as:

```
a = []
for item in page_content:
    # data = some xy logic on HTML file
    a.append(data)
```

Now write this list to the file using: [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump)

Comment: The file I'm talking about is Facebook's home page source.

Comment: Updated the answer. You may find it useful

Comment: @vmonteco The original file is HTML. However, I thought converting it to txt make it easier. So yes. The content is HTML basically.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I recive this message when I run the code. UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 64671: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @Nathan Could you provide a sample of the file and of what you're searching and expecting to find in it? You didn't provide HTML.

Comment: @vmonteco The file is your Facebook home page's source. I can't yet post pictures in my question.

Comment: @Nathan I don't see how posting pictures and HTML are related.

Comment: @vmonteco Sorry I misunderstood. If you have a Facebook account,  go to your home page and see the page source. That's the file I'm talking about.

Comment: @vmonteco I added a sample of the file in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to throw this out there even though I agree with all the comments about just dealing with the html directly or using Facebook's API (probably the safest way), but open file objects in Python can be used as a generator yielding lines without reading the entire file into memory and the re module can be used to extract information from text.

This can be done like so:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r"(?:some_keyword:\s\[)(.*?)\]")

with open("filename.txt", "r") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        for match in regex.findall(line):
            print(match)
```

Of course this only works if the file is in a "line-based" format, but the end effect is that only the line you are on is loaded into memory at any one time.

[here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) is the Python 2 docs for the `re` module

[here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html) is the Python 3 docs for the `re` module

I cannot find documentation which details the generator capabilities of file objects in Python, it seems to be one of those well-known secrets...Please feel free to edit and remove this paragraph if you know where in the Python docs this is detailed.